# bookdown encoding set to LATIN1 instead of UTF-8

Tags: r, bookdown

Why when i build a book using `build book` button it sets my encoding to `LATIN1` instead of `UTF-8`?
Also, whenever i open a chapter (.Rmd file) i've got reopen it with UTF-8 encoding 'cause it changes back do LATIN1 even if i have just saved it in UTF-8.

```
==> rmarkdown::render_site(output_format = 'bookdown::gitbook', encoding = 'LATIN1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my Project's encoding was set to LATIN1 (Project options - code editing - Text encoding).